# Implement inheritance and polymorhpic methods in python for one partent and two child classes?

Tags: python

I am confused at an assignment I am doing. I think I might misunderstand the directions. The part that is confusing me is how to use inheritance and polymorphism in the child classes/methods. I have three classes. A parent class called GisData and two child classes, one called RasterData the other called VectorData. From the diagram my teacher gave me I was able to fill out the methods and I think I have the basic parts of the code down. But I am confused at how to call methods from the parent class into the child class. For example in the assignment it calls for this to happen in the child classes (diagram illustrates this):

Here is the diagram:
[image]

Here is the code I am to implement using inheritance/polymorphism:

reportProjection:

- “projection reported for file
  xxxx”
- Return Projection_info

reportExtent: same as reportProjection except:

- saying “geographic extent” instead of
  “Projection_info”
- returning extent instead of Projection_info

read/write in GisData:

- “read (or write) in GisData class”

---

Before all this I was to do the following task, which I think I have completed in my code below:

DIRECTIONS: implement the classes, inheritance, and methods as shown in the diagram.

- In each class, use **init** to initialize the attributes as specified. Access control is not required.
- Methods: print out message to indicate use of method. No need to
  implement an actual procedure, which we don’t know anyway. The
  following are the requirements for the printouts for each method:

  __ init__:

  - “in **init** of class xxx”
  - “attribute xxx initiated”
  - This method does not take any argument in the GisData, RasterData,
    and VectorData classes. In each of the file format class, it should
    take a file name as the sole argument and assignment that name to a
    filename attribute.

The code:

```
class GisData:
    Projection_info = None
    Geog_extent = None

    def __init__(self):
        print("This is the initialization method for the GisData class")
        print(“in __init__ of class GisData”)


    def reportProjection(self):
        print("This method reports the projection of the GIS data")


    def reportExtent(self): 
        print("This method reports the extent of the GIS data")


    def read(self): 
        print("This method reads GIS data")


    def write(self):
        print("This method writes GIS data")


class RasterData(GisData):
    Num_rows = 0
    Num_cols = 0
    Num_layers = 0
    Raster_Format = 'BSQ'
    data_layers = None

    def __init__(self):
        print("This is the initialization method of the RasterData class")
        print(“in __init__ of class RasterData”)




    def BandMath(self):
        print("This method does band math")


class VectorData(GisData):
    Num_layers = 0
    Layers = None
    Geometry = None

    def __init__(self):
        print("This is the initialization method of the VectorData class")
        print(“in __init__ of class VectorData”)


    def Buffer(self):
        print("This method buffers vector data")

    def Rasterization(self):
        print("This method rasterizes vector data")



class TiffFile(RasterData):

    def __init__(TiffFile):
        print("This is the initialization method of the TiffFile class")
        print(“in __init__ of class TiffFile”)
        print(“attribute TiffFile initiated”)
        FileName = TiffFile


class JP2File(RasterData):

    def __init__(JP2File):
        print("This is the initialization method of the JP2File class")
        print(“in __init__ of class JP2File”)
        print(“attribute JP2File initiated”)
        FileName = JP2File


class SidFile(RasterData):

    def __init__(SidFile):
        print("This is the initialization method of the SidFile class")
        print(“in __init__ of class SidFile”)
        print(“attribute TiffFile initiated”)
        FileName = SidFile


class HdFile(RasterData):

    def __init__(HdFile):
        print("This is the initialization method of the HdFile class")
        print(“in __init__ of class HdFile”)
        FileName = HdFile


class ShpFile(VectorData):

    def __init__(ShpFile):
        print("This is the initialization method of the ShpFile class")
        print(“in __init__ of class ShpFile”)
        FileName = ShpFile


class KmzFile(VectoraData):

    def __init__(KmzFile):
        print("This is the initialization method of the KmzFile class")
        print(“in __init__ of class KmzFile”)
        FileName = KmzFile


class GdbFile(VectorData):

    def __init__(GdbFile):
        print("This is the initialization method of the GdbFile class")
        print(“in __init__ of class GdbFile”)
        print(“attribute xxx initiated”)
        FileName = GbdFile


class OsmFile(VectorData):

    def __init__(OsmFile):
        print("This is the initialization method of the OsmFile class")
        print(“in __init__ of class OsmFile”)
        FileName = OsmFile
```

Does what I have look correct? I feel stuck on how to implement those methods in the child classes from the parent class methods. Afterwards I'll have to create objects for each class and call each method. Such as:
- Obj.read 
- Obj.reportProjection 
- Obj.reportExtent 
- Obj.BandMath 
- Obj.write

Would appreciate the assistance.
Thank you

Comment: Move this Question over to [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @stovfl as it contains broken code (look at the double quotes in several `print(“…”)` calls), it's unfortunately off-topic on Code Review in its current version.

Comment: @Zeta: I got your point. In its current version still to **broad**.

Comment: @stovfl Didn't say that it's on-topic on SO either :). It's a question for a mentor or tutor in its current form, not for SO.

Comment: @Zeta thank you. How could I use inheritance and polymorphism here in the child classes? I want to call the methods reportProjection, reportExtent, and read/write in GisData but in the child classes. How would I do that?